# Fusion on OSX 12.6.5 Monterrey - Transport (VMDB) error-14 Pipe connection has been boken

Tags: macos-monterey, vmware-fusion

I'm having issues on VMware fusion 13. There is no way on create any Virtual image. I'm just receiving this error "Transport (VMDB) error-14 Pipe connection has been boken".

I've tried to reinstall, and clean up eveything related to VMfusion.. did not work.

I've tried many solutions.. niether work.

I'm sure you need more context.. but I prefer you to ask me what you need me to share.. I don't know where to start with.

Any help?

Thanks